# Webmail script with smime support

Tags: encryption, webmail, smime

Have anyone know anything of any webmail script which provide s/mime support? I'm using roundcube but it doesn't provide it yet.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send encrypted and/or signed messages using S/MIME format you may give a try to [Fossa.me](https://fossa.me). It is not a standalone solution, but an extension to Google Chrome browser. Also, you will need to have a GMail account. However, runs in a browser like a script.

*Disclaimer: I am developer of that extension and PKI services used by it.*